# Multiple inheritance for abstract classes in C++

Tags: java, c++, class, inheritance, abstract

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance for abstract classes, but I'm trying to do the equivalent of this in C++:

```
//this is Java-style pseudocode
public abstract class Rectangle{
    public abstract double getHeight();
    public abstract double getWidth();
    public double getHeight(){
        return getWidth()*getHeight();
    }
}

public abstract class Container{
    public abstract void printTypes();
    public abstract void printEachElement();
    public void printContainerStuff(){
        System.out.print("Has the types: ");
        printTypes();
        System.out.print("List of elements: ");
        printEachElement();
    }
}

public abstract class Array extends Rectangle, Container{ //this can't be done in Java, but what about C++?

}
```

Is there an equivalent of Java abstract classes in C++ that would make it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ allows multiple inheritance. So that is allowed in C++.

And the equivalent of Java's abstract class in C++ is a class that has at least one *pure* `virtual` member function.

So the equivalent of the Java code in C++ would be this:

```
class Rectangle
{
  public:
    virtual double getHeight() = 0;
    virtual double getWidth() = 0;
    double getHeight(){
        return getWidth()*getHeight();
    }
};

class Container(){
  public:
    virtual void printTypes() = 0;
    virtual void printEachElement() =0;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited your answer before noticing that hmjd already provide the information missing from yours. I rollbacked, I don't know if that's the thing to do or not...

Comment: Do pure virtual functions in C++ act like abstract methods in Java?

Comment: Also, is it possible to create methods in a class that can be called without creating an instance of the class (like static methods in Java?)

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Yes. You can have static member functions also. Search for it.

Answer (score 3):

To make a class abstract in C++ at least one member function must be pure virtual:

```
class X
{
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
```

As has already been stated, multiple inheritance is permitted in C++:

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    virtual double getHeight() = 0;
    virtual double getWidth() = 0;
    double getHeight(){
        return getWidth()*getHeight();
    }
};

class Container
{
public:
    virtual void printTypes() = 0;
    virtual void printEachElement() = 0;
};

class Array: public Rectangle, public Container
{
    // If the pure virtual member functions in the base classes
    // are not implemented then this class is also abstract.
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for Java interfaces.

```
public abstract class Rectangle{
    public abstract double getHeight();
    public abstract double getWidth();
    public double getHeight(){
        return getWidth()*getHeight();
    }
}

public interface Container {
    public void printTypes();
    public void printEachElement();
}

public abstract class Array extends Rectangle implements Container {
}
```

In C++ you can have multiple inheritance. You can also have something like Java interfaces with pure virtual methods.

```
class Container {
    public:
        virtual void printTypes() = 0;
        virtual void printEachElement() = 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for multiple inheritance of abstract classes - in Java this isn't possible, but in C++ I think it is possible. Interfaces can't implement their own methods, but abstract classes can.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - You're correct on all counts. In Java you can implement multiple interfaces, but you can only inherit from one class (`Object`, if you don't specify anything else). In C++, you can inherit from any number of classes, abstract or not.

Answer (score -1):

If you want inheritance behavior. (The code is in Java, You can try some thing like this in c++)

```
abstract class Rectangle{

    public abstract double getHeight();
    public abstract double getWidth();
    public double getHeight(){
        return getWidth()*getHeight();
    }
}

abstract class Container extends Rectangle{
    public abstract void printTypes();
    public abstract void printEachElement();
}

abstract class Array extends Container{ 

}
```

Comment: I don't want the Container class to extend Rectangle. I want other non-Rectangle classes (for example, a 3-dimensional arraylist) to extend it as well.